# What happens upon Socket acceptance?

Tags: sockets, networking

What happens when a server listening to a socket accepts a connection ?

My professor slides include this explanation

> If everything goes well, the server accepts the connection. Upon acceptance, the server gets a new socket bounds to a different port. It needs a new socket (consequently a different port number) so that it can continue to listen to the original socket for connection requests while serving the connected client.

But I don't feel like this is correct. because if on high load servers ports will run out easily.

So what exactly happens ?? and how actually multi-threading acts with responding t sockets ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. Your professor's slide is wrong wrong wrong from start to finish. The new socket uses the same local port as the listening socket.

I will add that I really find this incident rather shocking. Ask your professor to explain the following `netstat` output:

```
TCP    0.0.0.0:389            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       2932
TCP    127.0.0.1:389          127.0.0.1:57863        ESTABLISHED     2932
```

Comment: you feel shocked, I feel that I have wasted 5 years of my life !!
Thank you sir for your answer and explanation on the duplicated question.

Comment: @ShadyAtef See edit. Ask your professor to explain it.